# Success message from Aura is recurring in every 4-5 seconds after updating case record

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have a Quick Action button button on case to update record and after the update show a Toast message as Success. But the toast is repeatedly coming after every 4-5 seconds. Also the case page layout section Accordions are closed after the action completion. Below is the code i have placed up on success call

```
                       var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                        toastEvent.setParams({
                            "title": "Success!",
                            "message" : "Successfully updated",
                            "type" :"success"
                        });
                        toastEvent.fire(); 
                        $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction").fire();
                        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
```

Is it that my refreshView is not working. Until i do a hard refresh manually on the page, the accordions are closed and i cannot view fields on the layout

Answer (score 0):

you may need to call the doInit method once again to refresh your view,
something like this in your component
<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doInit}" />